# How to show that $g$ is differentiable at $0?$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be analytic for $|z|<R$ with $f(0)=0.$ How to show that $$g(z)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{f(z)}{z},&0<|z|<R\\f'(0),&z=0\end{cases}$$ is differentiable at $0?$

As far as I can observe,

$$\lim_{z\to0}\dfrac{g(z)-g(0)}{z}=\lim_{z\to0}\dfrac{\dfrac{f(z)}{z}-f'(0)}{z}=\lim_{z\to0}\dfrac{\dfrac{f(z)}{z}-\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(h)}{h}}{z}$$

What's next?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{f(z)}{z} = \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you aware of the fact that $f$ is analytic for $|z|<R$ if and only if $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n,$$ where the power series converges in the disk $|z|<R$, and where $a_n=\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ for all $n\ge 0$?

Comment: More to the point, what definitions of "analytic for $|z|<R$" do you know?

Comment: @CameronBuie in the context of complex analysis, "analytic" is often used interchangeably with "holomorphic" and so does not immediately bring to mind the notion of a power-series representation.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: True enough, which is why I brought it up and asked for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

$g$ is continuous at $0$ and analytic at the ring $Δ(0,R)-{0}$. By Cauchy's Theorem we have that $g$ is analytic everywhere. To prove what i say let's have a $r>0$ and $D(0,r)\subset Δ(0,R)$. Then $D(0,r)$ is open and convex and thus there is a$G:D(0,r)->\Bbb C$ such that $G'(z)=g(z)$ for every $z\in D(0,r)$. $G$ is analytic and thus $G'$ is analytic. So $g:D(0,r)->\Bbb C$ is analytic and thus $g:Δ(0,R)->\Bbb C$ is analytic